# Error: No elements in volume 1, GMSH module from PYTHON

Tags: python, mesh, gmsh

I'm trying to remesh some .stl files, containing geometries already processed with some smoothing algorithm, with the gmsh module on python. The remeshing algorithm works fine for many .stl files. However, for some of them no 3D remeshing is performed, because 3D meshing returns some intersection bewteen faces, and then shows the message "Error: no elements in volume 1"

Here is the code:

```
import gmsh
import math 
import sys

gmsh.initialize()
gmsh.option.setNumber('Mesh.Algorithm3D', 4)

gmsh.onelab.set("""[
{
"type":"number",
"name":"Parameters/Angle for surface detection",
"values":[120],
"min":20,
"max":120,
"step":1
},
{
"type":"number",
"name":"Parameters/Create surfaces guaranteed to be parametrizable",
"values":[1],
"choices":[0, 1]
}
]""")

gmsh.clear()
name = 'filename'
gmsh.merge(name)

angle = gmsh.onelab.getNumber('Parameters/Angle for surface detection')[0]
forceParametrizablePatches = gmsh.onelab.getNumber(
    'Parameters/Create surfaces guaranteed to be parametrizable')[0]
includeBoundary = False
curveAngle = 180
gmsh.model.mesh.classifySurfaces(angle * math.pi / 180., includeBoundary,
                                forceParametrizablePatches,
                                curveAngle * math.pi / 180.)
gmsh.model.mesh.createGeometry()

s = gmsh.model.getEntities(2)
l = gmsh.model.geo.addSurfaceLoop([e[1] for e in s])
gmsh.model.geo.addVolume([l])
gmsh.model.geo.synchronize()

f = gmsh.model.mesh.field.add("MathEval")
gmsh.model.mesh.field.setString(f, "F", "0.5")
gmsh.model.mesh.field.setAsBackgroundMesh(f)

v = gmsh.model.getEntities(3)
gmsh.model.add_physical_group(3, [e[1] for e in v])

gmsh.model.mesh.generate()
gmsh.write('Calcium_new.mesh')

gmsh.finalize()
```

I don't know if there is the possibility to solve this problem so that for all my geometries will work fine, or if I can manage these self-intersections during remeshing.

Comment: Hello, can you please share the full error traceback. Which function call and line does it happen.

Comment: It verifies at command line: gmsh.model.mesh.generate()
Error displayed

An exception verified: Exception
No elements in volume 1

@Daraan